# testing solidity - Error: invalid BigNumber value, when passing object as argument

Tags: testing, solidity, ethers.js, hardhat, bignumber.js

I have a function in my Solidity which takes a struct as first parameter:

```js
function mintGenesisAnimal(AnimalInfo memory _animalInfo, string memory _tokenUri) onlyOwner public {
    // ...
}
```

but when I'm trying to test this function with the code below:

```js
const animalInfo = {
    raceName: 'Tiger',
}

await Animal.mintGenesisAnimal(animalInfo, 'https://google.com')
```

The test fails with a weird issue relative to "BigNumber":
`Error: invalid BigNumber value (argument="value", value=undefined, code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=bignumber/5.6.0)`

Why is a BigNumber reported when I'm trying to pass a struct (js object) as parameter ?

Comment: I have the same error. but your error seems like the value is undefined.
Error: invalid BigNumber value (argument="value", value={"value":"25000000000000000"}, code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=bignumber/5.6.0)